# SQL difference between primary key(x, y) and primary key(x), unique(y)

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL what is the difference between this

```
create table marriage (
    person1 int not null references human on delete cascade,
    person2 int not null references human on delete cascade,
    primary key (person1, person2)
);
```

and this

```
create table marriage (
    person1 int not null references human on delete cascade,
    person2 int not null references human on delete cascade,
    primary key (person1),
    unique (person2)
);
```

And does the table with two primary keys prevent this?

```
marriage:    

person1 | person2
   1         2
   2         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index is a unique index on two columns: that means that the combination of both should be unique. The rows 1,2 and 2,1 are not violating the index since the index treats them as a set. 1,2 and 1,3 don't violate the index either.

The second sample contains two indexes and both need to be unique. That means that rows with 1,2 and 1,3 violate the index constraints.